# do i need to write decode() everytime for printing data

Tags: python, fetch, decode

am fetching data from my database and printing it but i have to write every time this `decode()` someone said that add `"charset=utf"` then you dont need to add `decode()` everytime, i did it but this is not working i have to write decode() everytime with print.

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
  database="testing",
  charset = 'utf8',
  use_unicode=True
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE id =2 limit 1"

mycursor.execute(sql)

row = mycursor.fetchone()

while row is not None:
    print(row[0]) #this is not working
    print(row.decode(0))
    print(row.decode(1))
    print(row.decode(2))
    row = mycursor.fetchone()
```

Also Tried with For but getting same results.

```
for i in row:
  print(i[1])
```

My DB Looks like this (its ez just for practice purpose)

```
id,name,age,city
```

these are the 4 columns

Problem: if i dont add `decode()` with print so its showing data like this.

```
print(row[1])

bytearray(b'Richard')
```

Comment: Try adding `use_unicode=True,` to the list of parameters passed to `mysql.connector.connect()` and see if that works, please.

Comment: Without the actual data it is hard to help you. The variable `row` after `fetchone()` is a Tuple object in Python. I do not understand why you loop over it with a while? You can use: `for element in row:`

Comment: @TimPietzcker sorry it didn't work

Comment: @LucaAngioloni even i used for loop but there also when i have to print data i need to write code like this    print(row[3].decode())

Comment: @LucaAngioloni i have updated question

Comment: @Cathrine Ah ok, now it makes more sense... In the code you provided you wrote row.decode() without the index [i]. Yeah so it is a problem of encoding... I believe that it is easier and less painful to just write decode() than to find a weird solution... Most of all don't index yourself, use a for!

Comment: @LucaAngioloni u mean there is no alternate of this? i have to write decode? i also tried this but its giving output like this code: for i in row:
  print(i[1])
 Output:  bytearray(b'richard')

Comment: @Cathrine What is so wrong about decode? Just call it and be over with it. If you write good code you have to write decode once.

Comment: @LucaAngioloni i think this is not a good practice & am sure there is a solution for it, that's why i asked here.